# Android: How to add TextView Dynamically?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm building a surveying app. On the creation of survey activity, I am having trouble how to implement the number of options to a particular survey?

For example let's say I want to ask:

```
What is your favourite Programming language?
1. C++
2. Java
3. C#
4. Python
5. I hate programming!!
```

Then in the next survey, I want to ask a Yes or No question:

```
Do you like ice cream?
1. Yes
2. No
```

See, options vary depending on the survey question; therefore, I am thinking of first asking the user how many options they would like to have then show them. However, I am unsure of going about doing so.

Can anyone please help me? 
I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What specific problems are you facing and what have you tried?

Comment: ViewGroup has a method called addView. The addView method should be what you are after. Frame-, Linear- and RelaviteLayouts derive from ViewGroup.

Answer (score 1):

You can add TextView dynamically with this code

```
TextView textView = new TextView(<context intance here>);
textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setText("Sample Text");
```

Then add created TextView instance to your view container:

```
viewContainer.addView(textView);
```

You can change your view's layouting by its LayoutParams.

Comment: thanks! I'm going to be using sqlite to implement this. Therefore, I am wondering how do I structure my database table for the options?

Answer (score 0):

if you have radio buttons to chose from your answers you can try to only show as many radio buttons as many answers you have with a if clause